# Setting pointer-events on an SVG-path using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, pointer-events

I am using a JavaScript-function to enable and disable `pointer-events` on a click. The `<svg>` is a child of a child of the `<main>`-element.

My first try was:

```
let el = jQuery( "main" );
el.css({ "pointer-events": "none" });
```

This should work because the `pointer-events` property is inherited. And it does. Pointer-events are disabled on all elements except on the `path` in my `svg`.
Then, after googling for a while, I found out that `pointer-events` in `svg` is an element's attribute.

So I tried:

```
let el = jQuery( "main" );
console.log( el.find( "path" ).attr( "pointer-events" ) ); // which returns: undefined

el.css({ "pointer-events": "none" });
el.find( "path" ).attr( "pointer-events", "none" );
console.log( el.find( "path" ).attr( "pointer-events" ) ); // which returns: none
```

So the attribute gets set, but it isn't working. The path still responds to `hover`- and to `click`-events.

Now i am stuck because I don't understand this.

Comment: It might be helpfull to explain the downvote.

Comment: Your question should include enough code to reproduce the issue. Please create a [MRE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was quite a silly question. Because of a mistake elsewhere in the code it did not work.

Though apparently the `svg` does not inherit the `pointer-events`-property. But
`el.find( "path" ).css( "pointer-events": "none" );`
works perfectly.

@Turnip is quite right in his comment. If you really need help you want to post all the relevant code.

I hope this will help somebody in the future.